# Generating a WsHttpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding using "Add Service Reference" in VS2010

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have successfully added a Service Reference using the "Add Service Reference" dialog in VS2010.  However, when I try to access said web service methods, I get the following ProtocolException:

```
Test method Test.Entities.DocumentumServiceClient_Tests.Can_Read_Client_Message threw
exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type multipart/related; 
type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:976dd31d-c531-4298-b12c-e799c8eb4bed"; 
start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml" of the response message
does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). 
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented
properly. The first 919 bytes of the response were: <code>

'--uuid:976dd31d-c531-4298-b12c-e799c8eb4bed
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
     <ns8:getRepositoryNameResponse 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:dfs-dm-core-profiles="http://irrelevant.com/" 
           xmlns:dfs-dm-core-context="http://irrelevant2.com/"
           xmlns:dfs-dm-core-properties="http://irrelevant3.com/" 
           xmlns:dfs-dm-core-content="irrelevant4.com/" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:ns8="http://irrelevant5.com/">           
        <return>to the Dagobah system</return>
     </ns8:getRepositoryNameResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
--uuid:976dd31d-c531-4298-b12c-e799c8eb4bed--'.
```

This all seems, after an extensive googling, to be a mismatch between SOAP 1.2 on the server and SOAP 1.1 in my project.  I should apparently be using WSHttpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding.  Here is the generated relevant section of app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://irrelevant.com/Service"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="CMSPersistantManagerServiceServiceSoapBinding"
              contract="DocumentumService.CMSPersistentManagerService"  
              name="CMSPersistentManagerServicePort" />
  </client>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DfsAgentService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="DfsContextRegistryService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="DfsDefaultService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="CMSPersistantManagerServiceServiceSoapBinding"
      closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Is there something different I should be doing to tell the service reference dialog to generate a 1.2 version with WSHttpBinding?  Is it the fault of the WSDL?  Any assistance would be appreciated, as I am at the end of my google-rope.

Comment: It should be using whatever the server is using.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  However, the Add Service Reference dialog, as I stated, isn't generating a compatible service (apparently).  I get that they should match, I just don't understand how, if it reads the WSDL correctly, it is too stupid to pick the right binding.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a 3rd Party SOAP webserivice that I had no control over, I discovered that I had to be using SOAP 1.2, not the default SOAP 1.1 headers that Visual Studio adds with BasicHttpBinding .

The service I was consuming was not compatible with the security features of WSHttpBinding, so by creating a custom binding, you can get BasicHttpBinding to work with SOAP 1.2 but modifying your .config thus :

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="httpSoap12">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://server.com/interface/SoapService.asmx"
      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpSoap12"
      contract="Service.ThingsYouNeed" name="ThingsYouNeed" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Make these modifications to your config, after adding the service reference in Visual Studio 2010.

Hope this helps.